# Android Oreo : How long a JobService stays alive ?

Tags: android, performance, android-jobscheduler

I am trying to create a MQTT connection/Socket Connection in a background thread in a JobService. My concerns is, while I am creating the connection, the JobService just gets destroyed. Is it a way that it stays alive for sometime in background ? OR it will always get destroyed ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `JobService.jobFinshed`. Explanation here: [Android: How to use JobFinished of JobService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44554256/android-how-to-use-jobfinished-of-jobservice)

But in short: spawn a new thread when you wake up in `onStartJob` and return `true` value from the method (this tells the OS to not kill you and keep a wake lock for you). Then, after done working on separate thread, call `JobService.jobFinished` (from the bg thread you spawned) to finally tell OS to release wake lock and kill the scope/context.

Again, code example here: [Android: How to use JobFinished of JobService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44554256/android-how-to-use-jobfinished-of-jobservice)

Answer (score 0):

> How long a JobService stays alive?

Until the app is alive or you yourself kill the app.

In android O, even background services are automatically destroyed/killed by the OS as soon as the Application is swiped-off/killed.